# Not receiving LINK from Chainlink kovan faucet

Tags: testnets, chainlink, kovan

I attempted to get funds from kovan.chain.link to my metamask address and the money did not come through.

I got some errors as seen here: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x7c2a3ec1515f883039938f82602243c73fdd47aa52c161c4366926fa7b42ee78

"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]
ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender."

What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The faucet](https://kovan.chain.link/) temporarily ran out of LINK tokens and has been refilled. Try again and it will work.